# Sharepoint 2016 document master detail layout

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2016, document-management

I am new in SharePoint development. Right now I am working on a project for the Integrated Management System. We need to provide an easy navigation view for users where they can search and view the document in one place.

1. Is there any built-in web parts specifically for IMS available in SharePoint?
2. Or any web part available for document master-detail view, like a list of the document on the left side and selected document displays on the right side.
3. Or do I need to completely depend on the new SharePoint page development?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SharePoint 2016 on-premises and Office Online Server,
 the users can find documents using SharePoint Search, and view into the documents using the hoverpanel.
Please see [this blog post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/lystavlen/2012/10/08/the-new-hover-panel-in-sharepoint-online-search/) (the blog-post has a focus on SharePoint Online, but SharePoint 2016 and Office Online Server provide this feature on-premises as well)